Exception handling in grails 2.2.3
I am developing an old project (grails 2.2.3 based on jdk 7). I want to use something like @controllerAdvice for exception handling rather than try catch in every controller method and I am not sure it supports it. any other suggestions ?
The old code is using try catch blocks.

You can declare exception handling methods in the controller by convention, like so:
// grails-app/controllers/demo/DemoController.groovy
package demo
class DemoController {

    def someAction() {
        // do some work
    }

    def handleSQLException(SQLException e) {
        render 'A SQLException Was Handled'
    }

    def handleBatchUpdateException(BatchUpdateException e) {
        redirect controller: 'logging', action: 'batchProblem'
    }

    def handleNumberFormatException(NumberFormatException nfe) {
        [problemDescription: 'A Number Was Invalid']
    }
}

These exception handler methods can also be included in the controller using an abstract parent class or Trait.
See:
https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.5.x/guide/single.html#controllerExceptionHandling

I'm not sure those are available in v2.2.x as the OP specifies.

You can try using an ErrorController to handle all errors.
https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.2.x/guide/single.html#controllerExceptionHandling:~:text=Declarative%20Error%20Handling
We use Grails 2.5.6, on which you can set an ErrorController and then all errors (except the caught ones) will be handled by a def index() method.
Another way is mapping the Exceptions to a controller via UrlMappings (as the doc shows)
